# Things to do after installing Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, updates, software-recommendation

I'm new to Linux and I just installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS on my machine (dual booted with Win8). Can anybody recommend me a list of important things to do and software to install? I have done "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade" on my terminal already.

I am primarily looking for the best software for the following:

1. programming in C/C++/Java/Python (emulators/libraries)
2. media player supporting a HUGE range of formats (both audio & video)
3. torrent download/upload
4. compression/extraction of files supporting most (if not all) compression formats
5. music studio to create/edit music (MIDI and/or other formats) (possibly something like GarageBand(Mac) and/or LMMS(Win))

I'm also looking forward to know about any other set of tweaks, software, etc. which I should get to know to get better versed with Linux or stuff I would enjoy.

Comment: Too broad & opinions only. Other distros might have more of the programs you want pre-installed, like an audio/video distro maybe. Mint has playback of most video formats & archive extraction, and transmission. But just use all the Repos (contrib, nonfree...) ans search for what's available

Answer (score 2):

You questions seems to be a bit too broad, 
I will limit myself to answer the question in your title,
What to do after installing ubuntu.

There is a great website that published this kind of posts everytime a new version is released,
And this is what I have actually used mysel, back then...

http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/thingstweaks-to-do-after-install-of.html

**It answers your question about Codecs:**

> 13: Install Restricted Extras:
>
> There are some Restricted extras available in Ubuntu repositories
>   which can't be install while installation but you can install these
>   Restricted extras by yourself. Restricted extras contains: mp3
>   playback and decoding, support for various formats, fonts, java, flash
>   plugin, lame, dvd playback.  Terminal Command:

**`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`**

> 14: Codecs and Enable DVD Playback:
>
> If you are multimedia user and use Ubuntu for multimedia then these
>   codecs are very useful for you. You can install them by single
>   command. Terminal Command:

**`sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gxine libdvdread4 totem-mozilla icedax tagtool easytag id3tool lame nautilus-script-audio-convert libmad0 mpg321 libavcodec-extra`**

> Following command for Enable DVD Playback: Terminal Command:

**`sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`**

> For Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty install more codecs: Terminal Command:

**`sudo apt-get install libxine1-ffmpeg mencoder`**

> 15: Enable H.264 support for Firefox (Only for 14.04 Trusty):
>
> FFmpeg plugin for GSreamer is dropped from official Ubuntu 14.04
>   official repositories, Firefox doesn't support the H.264 codec. So you
>   can install it from third-party repository.
>   Enter following commands to install codec: Terminal Command:

**`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`**

It answers your question about Compression Tools:

> 16: Compression/Decompression tools:
>
> You can compress and decompress 7z, zip, gzip, rar, xz, tar, bz2, xar,
>   tar.gz, tar.bz, and many others.
>   Enter following command in terminal to install in your Terminal Command:

**`sudo apt-get install p7zip-rar p7zip-full unace unrar zip unzip sharutils rar uudeview mpack arj cabextract file-roller`**

**Regarding Bittorrent**, I recommend you to install qBittorrent, you won't need anything else.

**`sudo apt-get install qbittorrent`**

**And regarding your last question, about music tools**
You should look into **Ubuntu Studio**,
Even though it is a distribution in itself, I think you can just install all those packages, this tutorial may help you
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu%20Studio%20Upgrade%20from%20Ubuntu

well, after all I did answer all your questions

Answer (score 1):

To learn Python try [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/), it works fine and im using it.

Best Media Player is VLC **( Download it from Ubuntu Software Center )**

For torrents software, try qbittorrent **( Download it from Ubuntu Software Center )**